# Don't Starve Together - how to find each other

Tags: dont-starve-together

I've been playing Don't Starve Together with my finacé for a while and we've been going back and forth on how to find each other in the game. That is if one character is in a place the other one haven't been to yet you're invisible on the map.

How do you find each other in the game and can we push the game moderators into making a flashing game character dot on the map, one of your own character and one for my fiancé?

Comment: The game is designed so you can't find each other unless you're at a point on the map you've both found. If you're playing one character and the other player's character isn't at that point you're supposed to either wait, or go through the long process of working out how to find them again afterwards. That's the choice you made when you decided to leave them behind, and it's there by design. If you leave your partner for too long and neglect to set any sort of trail for them to find you then they will leave you in the wilderness on your own for a while. That's just how it is.

Comment: The best way to progress fast in DS together is also by splitting during some days, and respect a schedule for actions (one day wood farming, another stones, and some day hunting together for instance). This way you don't really care about your friend's position, as long as you prepare a Rally point before going alone. Just a lil tip passing by :)

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes it's really important to spend time in different parts of the woods. Also, your partner will have different skills than you and vice versa, so there will be certain tasks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it, but one way if you are playing on Steam is you can use the 'Invite to Watch' and have the other player watch you while you're playing. Then they can see where you are on the screen and if you load up the map they can use *your personal map* to *work out where they need to go and what they're going to do*. You can also both watch, but that can get confusing because of the number of screens you're going to both have to try to keep track of (you're going to have to try to understand what they're doing while you're away, as well as keeping track of what you yourself are trying to do). That *is* cheating, though.

What you're supposed to do is make sure when you go wandering off on your own you at least allow your partner a general idea of where you're at and don't leave them behind completely. Or if you do, you accept there are consequences. It takes more effort to do things the right way, but yeah, there's also the one that's basically cheating...

Answer (score 0):

There might be many solutions, but I have one.

If you have a base or any checkpoint both of you know about, tell the other person to go there and you should also go there too. If you arrive early, wait for the other person to come. However, if you do not have many checkpoint/base, then go to the Florid Postern. Both of you must have the Florid Postern on your map because the Florid Postern is where you enter the world. On your map, it will show as a portal with the colors white and black.

**NOTE:** The answer is assuming you do not have any mods. If you do have mods, then the appearance of the Florid Postern may be changed by the mod. However, the majority of the mods do not do this.